# LINQtoCSV looking for a way to chunk up a csv file into multiple data structures

Tags: c#, linq

I am looking for a creative way to essentially chunk a multi-format csv file into data structures.

For instance here is my csv

```
FILEHEADER;00;RSRGP;12345;20130415;
542740;60;FRED ROGERS;1Z7539320359483792;4000001388;20130415;0000000800;0000000000;UPS;Grnd;
542740;70;511-59049-019;00001;00001;
542740;80;000000001;000000001;
542740;60;FRED ROGERS;1Z753932032184736528;4000002092;20130415;0000000000;0000000000;UPS;Grnd;
542740;70;511-56957-019;00001;00001;
542740;70;511-58714-019;00002;00002;
542740;70;511-58715-188;00001;00001;
542740;70;511-58717-019;00002;00002;
542740;70;511-58722-188;00001;00001;
542740;80;000000007;000000007;
FILETRAILER;99;0000022;
```

As you see there are different record types in the csv. This is generally indicated by the second column (00, 60, 70, 80 99).  Rows with a record type of 60 indicate an order header and include a tracking number in the 4th column.  The order id is indicated in the first column of record types 60 and 70. So I have one order with multiple packages.

I'd like a good way to take the first order header and it's associated order line items (Record type 70) and shove it into a data structure, then take the next order header and it's associated line item and shove it into another data structure of the same type.

It's not as trivial as I first thought and now I've been staring long enough that I think I am lost in the trees.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't that be an SSV?  http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp

Comment: I should have clarified, I'm not rolling my own ssv. I am using LINQtoCSV but there doesn't appear to be a good way to do this... at least as far as I can tell yet.

Comment: But I will take a look FileHelpers and see if that does what I need. Thanks.

Comment: FileHelpers did the trick. Thanks!. I'd mark it as the answer if I could.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be Linq?

You can read the value line by line, and then use the .split(';') method of the line/string to split it into an array of substrings.

You can then check the value of the appropriate array entries and use these to fill up your data objects.

Comment: So long as you don't have to escape ;'s in the actual data, that might work, assuming the data is only similar to what is shown.  CSV is nowhere near as easy as most people assume it is, particularly if arbitrary content is allowed.